# relative topologies and open coverings

Tags: general-topology

Is it true that if we have an open cover $(V_i)_{i\in I}$ of a topological space $X$ with $I$ some index set, then in order to determine whether a set $U\subset X $ is open, it suffices to show that for all $i\in I$ we have $U\cap V_i$ is open in the relative topology of $V_i$?

Comment: Please do not jus ask. Include at least  your attempts to solve your problem. https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

If the $V_i$ weren't open, then not in general, no. That is true when the topology of $X$ is "generated by", or is *[coherent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_topology) with*, the $(V_i)_{i\in I}$.

However we can show that this holds if all $V_i$ are open. $U\cap V_i$ being open in $V_i$ means it equals $W\cap V_i$ for some open $W\subset X$, but because $V_i$ is open it follows $U\cap V_i=W\cap V_i$ is open in $X$.

Thus: $$U=\bigcup_{i\in I}(U\cap V_i)$$Is open in $X$.

By the way, the analogous result for closed sets is not true: if $(C_i)_{i\in I}$ is a closed cover of $X$, then it is not true that $F\cap C_i$ being closed in $C_i$ for each $i$ implies $F$ is closed in $X$.

A counterexample for that: any infinite nondiscrete T1 space $X$. Let $I=X$ and for each $x\in X$, let $C_x:=\{x\}$ which is closed. Because $X$ is nondiscrete, there exists a $K\subset X$ which is not closed. But $K\cap C_x$ is closed in $C_x$ for all $x$, trivially, and the $(C_x)_{x\in X}$ are a closed cover of $X$.